# pg_routing source and target column issue

Tags: qgis, pgrouting, road

I have created `pgr_createTopology()` function on my road data table which accurately assign source and target to destination road table, but I have an issue when I split a road segment in qgis it provide same values of source and targets to both road segments and after that running `pgr_createTopology()` function is not updating or assign new value for a new split segment which is actually split from old one.

one way which I have found is to null both columns and run `pgr_createTopology()` again which solves my problem but if I have huge data updating both fields with null again and again is not a good option.

Please provide me solution by which both columns are updating as after I split a road segment in qgis.

Comment: If you split a network link into two, just assign a new unique node ID value to the new node (source/target). You don't need to recreate the whole topology.